# Assigning dataframe data to dataframe label using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframe names that I would like to assign different dataframe data to.

```
filenames =[]

for i in np.arange(1,7):
    a = "C:\Users\...........\Python code\Cp error for MPE MR%s.csv" %(i)
    filenames.append(a)

dfs =[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6]

for i, j in enumerate(filenames):
    dfs[j]= pd.DataFrame.from_csv(i,header=0, index_col=None)
```

However, the following error code occurs:

```
NameError: name 'df1' is not defined
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am defining the list of values? Why can't a value in a list be assigned as a variable?

how can i put the following code in a loop?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filenames[0],header=0, index_col=None)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filenames[1],header=0, index_col=None)
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filenames[2],header=0, index_col=None)
df4 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filenames[3],header=0, index_col=None)
df5 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filenames[4],header=0, index_col=None)
df6 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filenames[5],header=0, index_col=None)
```

Comment: don't you want to swap `i` and `j` around? (assuming you meant `enumerate` instead of `iterate`)

Comment: what is `iterate`?

Comment: Sorry supposed to be enumerate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need `dict comprehension`, one possible way for `list` of files is use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

Sample files:

[a.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/files/a.csv), [b.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/files/b.csv), [c.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/files/c.csv).

```
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
#windows solution for files names - os.path.splitext(os.path.split(fp)[1])
dfs = {os.path.splitext(os.path.split(fp)[1])[0]:pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in files}
print (dfs)
{'b':    a  b  c  d
0  0  9  6  5
1  1  6  4  2, 'a':    a  b  c  d
0  0  1  2  5
1  1  5  8  3, 'c':    a  b  c  d
0  0  7  1  7
1  1  3  2  6}

print (dfs['a'])
   a  b  c  d
0  0  1  2  5
1  1  5  8  3
```

If same columns in each files is possible create one big `df` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
print (df)
     a  b  c  d
a 0  0  1  2  5
  1  1  5  8  3
b 0  0  9  6  5
  1  1  6  4  2
c 0  0  7  1  7
  1  1  3  2  6
```

EDIT:
Better instead `pd.DataFrame.from_csv` is use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

Solution with global variables:

```
#for df0, df1, df2...
for i, fp in enumerate(files):
    print (fp)
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, header=0, index_col=None)
    globals()['df' + str(i)] = df

print (df1)
   a  b  c  d
0  0  9  6  5
1  1  6  4  2
```

Better solution for list of `DataFrames` and selecting by positions:

```
#for dfs[0], dfs[1], dfs[2]...
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp, header=0, index_col=None) for fp in files]

print (dfs[1])
   a  b  c  d
0  0  9  6  5
1  1  6  4  2
```

Comment: But I am unable to edit dataframe properties using this method?

Comment: I think yes. You are 2 possible options - create one big `df` from all files or create dict of df.

Comment: or... i can do seperately.. df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filenames[0],header=0, index_col=None) for filename range(1,6)

Answer (score 0):

```
dfs =[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6]?
```

Why this string? Why not it should be:

```
dfs =[]
```

And yes, I think you swapped i and j, and it should be something like:

```
dfs.append(pd.DataFrame.from_csv(j,header=0, index_col=None))
```

And enumerate is redundant:

```
for f in filenames:
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f,header=0, index_col=None))
```